# Prob. 13, Sec. 30, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Every collection of disjoint open sets in a separable space is countable

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, separable-spaces

Here is Prob. 12, Sec. 30, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that if $X$ has a countable dense subset, every collection of disjoint open sets in $X$ is countable.

My Attempt:

> Let $D$ be a countable dense subset in the topological space $X$. Then $D \subset X$ and $\overline{D} = X$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a (pairwise) disjoint collection of open sets of $X$.
>
> For each $A \in \mathscr{A}$, we must have $$ A \cap D \neq \emptyset, $$
>   by Theorem 17.5 (a) in Munkres; let us choose a point $x_A \in A \cap D$.
>
> Now if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are any two distinct sets in $\mathscr{A}$, then since $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, therefore we must also have
>   $$ 
> \left( A_1 \cap D \right) \cap \left( A_2 \cap D \right) = \left( A_1 \cap A_2 \right) \cap D = \emptyset,
> $$
>   which implies that
>   $$ x_{A_1} \neq x_{A_2}. $$
>   [Please refer to the preceding paragraph.]
>
> Thus the map $\mathscr{A} \rightarrow D$, $A \mapsto x_A$ is an injection of $\mathscr{A}$ into the countable set $D$. Therefore the collection $\mathscr{A}$ must be countable.

Is this proof correct and satisfactory enough? Or, are there any lacunas?

Here I have assumed that our collection of open sets is pairwise disjoint.

What if our collection is disjoint in the sense that
$$ \bigcap_{A \in \mathscr{A} } A = \emptyset, $$
but there exist sets $A, A^\prime \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $A \cap A^\prime \neq \emptyset$? Does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: @MattSamuel yes, that's certainly helpful. In fact, it is essentially the same proof as mine. However, there is no answer over there to my query at the end of the above post.

Comment: What conclusion are you refering to exactly? The whole problem in Munkers or the fact that $A\mapsto x_A$ is injective? Or perhaps something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the the question in the last sentence, let $$
\mathscr{A}=\{B(0,r)|r\in\mathbb{R}\} \cup \{B(1,1/2)\}$$ where $B(x,r)$ is the open disk of radius $r$ centered at $x$ in the plane.

Then the intersection of $\mathscr{A}$ is empty and $\mathscr{A}$ in uncountable.

Comment: and what about my proof? How do you like it? Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Your proof is correct.